# Setting up non-www sub-domain on Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns

I'm sure my lack of understanding of how everything plugs together is affecting me here, but I've not been able to dig my answer out of the Heroku docs.

I'm still on the Heroku free account.
My app is on `https://infinite-island-xxxx.herokuap.com`  (as an example).

I've added my own domain using the toolbelt `heroku domain:add app.mydomain.info`

The docs suggest if I run `heroku domains` I'll get a list of domains, and the DNS Targets for setting up a CNAME.
I don't, I just get the following output:

```
=== infinite-island-xxxx Domain Names
app.mydomain.info
infinite-island-xxxx.herokuapp.com
```

I plan to set up a CNAME for `app.mydomain.info` to point to `mydomain.herokuapp.com`, but I have no real expectations of that working.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can set this up?

Thank you,

Comment: The "DNS target" is `infinite-island-xxxx.herokuapp.com` - add a CNAME with your DNS provider for `app.mydomain.info` with a value of `infinite-island-xxxx.herokuapp.com`

Comment: Oh, it's that simple?  How embarrassing.... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "DNS target" is `infinite-island-xxxx.herokuapp.com`.

You need to add a CNAME with your DNS provider for `app.mydomain.info` with a value of `infinite-island-xxxx.herokuapp.com` to point your domain to your Heroku application.